# Multidimensional PHP array to jQuery - Only seeing one result

Tags: php, jquery, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to use PHP and jQuery to create a dynamic search results page.

On the `PHP` side, a `SELECT` statement is called, where I check if all variables are set, add my HTML that I want to be used clientside, then put the variables in an array named `$result`.

Of the results of the database call, I also add the `longitude` and `latitude` in their own array, named `$pins`.

<del>I then create a multidimensional array called `$results`, and put the array together like so:</del>

```
$result = array('listing'=>$listing);
$pins = array('lat'=>$lat1,'lng'=>$lon2); 
$results = array('listing'=>$result,'pins'=>$pins);

echo json_encode($results);
```

Now, clientside I use jquery. The issue I'm facing, is there should be 2 results in total. However I see the same result repeated twice (I can confirm they should be unique). Here is my jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/updatedsearch.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
        q: search, 
        lng: coordinates[0], 
        lat: coordinates[1], 
        },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "undefined" || data == null) {
                    console.log("There was no search results or something similar");
                                } else {
                                var pins = [data.pins.lat, data.pins.lng];
                                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                                    $('#listings').append(data.listing.listing);
                                    console.log(pins);
                                    console.log(data);
                                });
                               }
                            },
```

Everything here works as it should, apart from when `$.each()` runs, it appears to be appending the same data twice.

I assume it's because of `.append(data.listing.listing);`, if I understand correctly I'm not looping through the array here, I'm effectively referencing `data.listing.listing[0]` - have I understood this correctly?

**Edit:** I now have an issue with my results appearing twice. There should be only two results, however there are four in total, it appears as though these have been duplicated.

`{"listing":["<div>This contains my HTML</div>"], "pins":"lat":"50.000000","lng":"-1.000000"}}`

I have run this though `jsonlint` and it appears invalid. Using PHP I have created this data as follows:

```
while($listrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list)) {
$listing[] = '<div>This contains my HTML</div>';

}

$pins = array("lat"=>$lat1, "lng"=>$lon2);
$results = array('listing'=>$listing, 'pins'=>$pins);


echo json_encode($results);
```

Have I misunderstood using multidimensional arrays, which is causing the error?

Comment: I'd like a better idea of what your `$results` looks like. Call your PHP script directly, and use dummy inputs (`q`,`lng`,`lat`), then in the script, do `print_r($result)` , `print_r($pins)` and `exit` right where you would otherwise do `echo json_encode(...)`.  Add to your question the results that get printed out.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks for your reply, I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you are not looping through the array. You are also not referencing the individual array items when you append.

Try:

```
$.each(data.listing.listing, function(i, item) {
    $('#listings').append(item);
});
```

---

When you do the following:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
```

You are looping through the properties of the `data` object. It has two properties: `listings` and `pins`, so the loop executes twice.

And for each iteration of the loop, you are appending the same value (`data.listing.listing`), which I assume is an array.

Instead, I think you want to iterate over the array, and append each item in the array.

---

EDIT: The PHP you show at the top of your question looks like it would generate JSON like this:

```
{
    "listing": { "listing": ["<div>This contains my HTML</div>"] },
    "pins": { "lat":"50.000000","lng":"-1.000000" }
}
```

But with your edit, you show JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "listing": ["<div>This contains my HTML</div>"],
    "pins": { "lat":"50.000000","lng":"-1.000000" }
}
```

If that is what your JSON looks like, you should use:

```
$.each(data.listing, function(i, item) {
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3s0yz7kf/)

Comment: Took a bit of messing around with but it finally worked, thanks for your help and explanation to help me understand in the future!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you intend your `$.each` to loop through the listings placed in `$results['listing']` in your PHP, but it's actually looping over the whole `$results`.

To better see what's going on, use a different name for the current item in your `$.each`.  Because you use `data`, the same name you use as the argument of your `success` callback, you're making the code harder to debug.  If you want to cycle through your listings, do the following inside the `success` callback:

```
$.each(data.listing, function(i, result)){
   $('#listings').append(result);
}
```

The JSON you posted:

```
{
    "listing":["<div>This contains my HTML</div>"], 
    "pins":    "lat":"50.000000","lng":"-1.000000"}
}
```

Is invalid because you're missing an opening bracket between `"pins":` and `"lat"`.  It should be

```
{
    "listing":["<div>This contains my HTML</div>"], 
    "pins":   {"lat":"50.000000","lng":"-1.000000"}
}
```